# Angular Material Card Paginator

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

This is the component ts file

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from "@angular/material";
import { FoodService } from "./food.service";
import { Food } from "./food";

@Component({
  selector: "app-food",
  templateUrl: "./food.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./food.component.scss"],
})
export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  food: Food[];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Food> = new MatTableDataSource<Food>(
    this.food
  );

  constructor(private foodService: FoodService) {
    this.food = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foodService.getFood().subscribe((data) => {
      this.food = data as Food[];
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

And the HTML file

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let f of food">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div>
          <img
            [src]="f.imgUrl | safe"
            alt=""
            class="example-header-image"
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
          />
        </div>

        <mat-card-title class="card-title">{{ f.title }}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle class="card-subtitle">{{
          f.subtitle
        }}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{ f.text }}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <mat-paginator
    [pageSize]="5"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[8, 16, 24, 32]"
  ></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Paginator Doesnt work it upload all the cards .
This is server side paginator alla data are taken from api;
I dont get it why it doesnt paginator detect the data and transform it to paginator...
Any idea ???

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the MatTableDataSource after you retrieve the data from the response.

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from "@angular/material";
import { FoodService } from "./food.service";
import { Food } from "./food";

@Component({
  selector: "app-food",
  templateUrl: "./food.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./food.component.scss"],
})

export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  food: Food[];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Food> = new MatTableDataSource<Food>(
    this.food
  );

  constructor(private foodService: FoodService) {
    this.food = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foodService.getFood().subscribe((data) => {
      this.food = data as Food[];
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Food>(this.food);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```